# jQuery UI not linking to my page (transparent background)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter, background, datepicker

I'm using jQuery for the first time because I want to make use of the datepicker.
I have the datepicker working fine, but the background of it is transparent.
I have downloaded the *ui-lightness* theme and I'm trying to include it in the php page.
Here is the code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

My directory structure looks like this:
¦-css
¦--ui-lightness
¦---jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css
¦-myPhpPage.php

**My question is, why is my css file not linking to my php page?**

Comment: Yes, I'm using CodeIgniter. I didn't think that would make much of a difference though.

Comment: it makes difference, put css folder on application folder, and try `<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?> . css/....`

Comment: I tried exactly what you suggested and the background is still transparent. The source of the php page was: `http://127.0.0.1/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css`

Comment: have you modified your php config.php file? plz read this http://codeigniter.com/wiki/css

Comment: @undefined: I only changed one thing in the *config.php* file: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/';`.
I read the link you posted but can't find those configurations. I tried to open the *.htaccess* file but it only read `Deny from all`

Comment: don't change that htaccess file, there is no need to modify that file, as you have modified the base url if you put css files here: `application/css` the css should be loaded.

Comment: @undefined: Thanks. The directory is: `application/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css` it is still appearing as a transparent calendar. The source is: `<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working now.
I moved the `css` to one directory above my `application` folder.
The source remains as: `<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />` 
@undefined: thanks for all your help! I appreciate it.